# Recognizing taps but forwarding other gestures to another view

Tags: ios

I am using a `UIPageViewController` to display some content which can be horizontally paginated with a swipe. I want to add a button or view that, on tap, will progress the scroll view to the next page. The 'next' image displayed will be quite small, but the tappable area of the button or view will be large - perhaps even the entire right half of the screen. However, if the user begins a swipe gesture on the area covered by that button, the `UIPageViewController` should scroll as expected.

How can I respond to button taps, but forward any swipe gestures to the underlying view?

Note that I am using `UIPageViewController` so I have no access to its `UIScrollView`.

[image]

Comment: You don't like the option of adding the tappable view to the content view controllers themselves?

Comment: Interesting, I ruled it out since I don't I want the chevron to scroll with the content, but I suppose there's no reason the chevron and the tappable view need to be  the same view. I still think I'd prefer to have all of the navigation and associated views in the pager but this is a great backup plan, thanks for suggesting it.